# Difference between git@github.com:... and https://github.com/...?

Tags: git, github, repository

I've recently attempted building a project which had various dependencies declared as Github links. The links were a mixture of links to public Github repositories and private Github Enterprise repositories of my company.

Some of the links were in format

```
https://github.com/project/repo.git
```

And some were in format

```
git@github.com:project/repo.git
```

What exactly is the difference between such formats and which format is intended to be used for what purpose?

Comment: The `git:` or `https:` prefix specifies the *scheme*; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator. The `git:` scheme directs Git to use the Git protocol (which is built in to Git itself). The `https:` scheme directs Git to use HTTP over SSL, via libcurl. An `ssh:` prefix directs Git to use ssh, and `user@host:path` is shorthand for `ssh://user@host/path`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

git can operate on a variety of different protocols

**http(s)** like **https://github.com/project/repo.git**

It uses the port 443 (or 80 for http), it allows both read and write access, password for auth (like on github it allows anonymous read access but asks a paasword for write).and Firewall friendly (it does not require any infra configuration).

**ssh** like **git@github.com:project/repo.git**

It uses the port 22, it allows both read and write access, requires SSH Keys for auth so if you give git your public ssh key, your ssh protocol will use your private key for authentication with git, so you will not need to provide a username password.

with SSH you will not be asked to provide your password each time you use the git push command as the ssh protocol will use you private key for authentication with the repository.

Comment: So there is no reason to prefer ssh format when cloning from a public Github repo? I realized that using ssh format without setting up public ssh key may cause some problems on some machines such as git throwing couple extra prompts before cloning. This can make the process of automatically cloning dependencies crash.

Answer (score 3):

`https://github.com/project/repo.git`

is HTTPS URL

`git@github.com:project/repo.git`

is SSH URL

both can be used to do git file transfers but github recommends HTTPS over SSH URLs because These URLs work everywhere--even if you are behind a firewall or proxy.

refer https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/ for more information.